# about well-defined integral kernel

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ measurable function such that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\phi(x,y)|\ dx \leq M\ , \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\phi(x,y)|\ dy \leq M\,.$$
Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $1\leq p \leq \infty$.
Then
$$\text{for a.e. }y\in\mathbb{R}^n\text{ the function }x\mapsto \phi(x,y)f(x)\text{ belongs to }L^1(\mathbb{R^n})\ ;$$

$$\text{the function } y\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(x,y)\ f(x)\ dx \text{ belongs to }L^p(\mathbb{R^n})\ .$$

For $p=1$ the proof is simple (I used Fubini's theorem). Can you help me with $p>1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Using $(\int |\phi(x, y)|\ |f(x)| dx)^p \le (\int |\phi(x, y)|dx)^{p-1} (\int |\phi(x, y)||f^p(x)|dx )$.

Comment: ... which is a consequence of Jensen inequality.
And now I manage to do the proof. Thank you!